# How to get Three-letter-native-language-names?

Tags: vb.net, windows, cultureinfo, iso

A `TwoLetterISOLanguageName`, a `ThreeLetterIsoLanguageName`, a `EnglishName`, a `NativeName`, a `DisplayName` etc. are possible to get through `CultureInfo`.

e.g.:

```
Dim buffer As String = "IetfLanguageTag" & ControlChars.Tab & _
                       "TwoLetterISOLanguageName" & ControlChars.Tab & _
                       "ThreeLetterISOLanguageName" & ControlChars.Tab & _
                       "EnglishName" & ControlChars.Tab & _
                       "NativeName" & ControlChars.Tab & _
                       "Name" & ControlChars.Tab & _
                       "DisplayName" & _
                       Environment.NewLine

For Each ci As CultureInfo In System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.InstalledWin32Cultures)
   buffer &= ci.IetfLanguageTag & ControlChars.Tab & _
             ci.TwoLetterISOLanguageName & ControlChars.Tab & _
             ci.ThreeLetterISOLanguageName & ControlChars.Tab & _
             ci.EnglishName & ControlChars.Tab & _
             ci.NativeName & ControlChars.Tab & _
             ci.Name & ControlChars.Tab & _
             ci.DisplayName & _
             Environment.NewLine
Next
My.Computer.Clipboard.SetText(buffer)
```

But... **Question !**

How to get the Three-letter-**native**-language-names (like the ones in Windows 8.1; see the picture below)? Or are they stored somewhere in the registry or is it just a trim* of a `NativeName`?

*(*) I'm not sure about trim, because of Japanese, for example.*

[image: Windows 8 Language bar]

Thank you!

Comment: What exact version of Windows 8 are you using? On my Windows 8 (8.0) machine, the language selection list looks very differently; it uses non-native two-letter codes.

Comment: Windows 8.1 64-bit 6.3.9600

Comment: I didn't know it was not the same on Windows 8.0. Whatever, you see the start-button on the picture.

Comment: Usually you can upgrade to Windows 8.1 for free, I guess.

Comment: well you could have a translate method to return the definition of the "EN" for example a switch statement

Comment: @Pogrindis: I suppose the OP does not want to create a `switch` block with >6,000 `case`s if there is already an mechanism provided by .NET that does the same…

Comment: @stakx I would hope not! ^^ But its a loose `solution` for a masochist

Comment: It's maybe an icon shown by API through IME, and not a text.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh848069(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not derived from the native names algorithmically. These are not exposed in any public API.